# Configure vscode json formatting spaces

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

I would like to configure the vscode to format my JSON objects with 2 spaces of indent, not 4 as it does by default. How can I do this?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42118981/2631715 - instead of `[python]` you should be able to use `[json]`.

Comment: Thanks. Looks like JSON is subject to the same limitations described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/42118981/6139071

Answer (score 27):

Paste in this lines in settings.json in VSCode, and you're all set:

```
"[json]": {
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.tabSize": 2
}
```

Comment: @JonathanPool I do not know why. I ti works for project settings.json in `.vscode/settings.json` and in global settings.json `~/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Answer (score 3):

Install the editor config plugin.

```
ext install EditorConfig
```

Add an `.editorconfig` file to your project root with the following:

```
[*.json]
indent_style = space
indent_size = 2
```

See also:

https://github.com/editorconfig/editorconfig-vscode

http://editorconfig.org/