# How to avoid the tailing space space after ":" in using Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json.net

After writing the JSON into the file using

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonToWrite, Formatting.Indented)).
```

I am getting a tailing space after every ":". How to avoid it?

Current in red, expected in Green
[image]

Comment: What's wrong about it? Not sure if there is an option for this, at all.

Comment: I'm not sure you can. It looks like it's fairly hard-coded into the library. See the code [here](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/52e257ee57899296d81a868b32300f0b3cfeacbe/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonWriter.cs#L881-L886).

Comment: question: what's the problem with it? _no_ JSON parsing library should have trouble with whitespaces

Comment: If you absolutely insist, you could replace all `": "` by `":"` in the resulting string. But meh ...

Comment: @Fildor more like `": "` -> `":"` (with quotes) to reduce the risk of modifying the keys/values.

Comment: @abdusco That's what I wrote, didn't I?

Comment: I have to change one field in the json. As I rewrite the file, during git diff all the lines would change due to whitespace.

Comment: @Fildor True, but it was a bit ambiguous :)

Comment: @eoeo But surely once you do it one time, in future it will have those spaces and thus not be a problem?

Comment: _"As I rewrite the file, during git diff all the lines would change due to whitespace."_ - only once. ;)

Comment: @abdusco It's a terrible idea anyway and I already regret having suggested it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Configure vscode json formatting spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42120299/configure-vscode-json-formatting-spaces)

Comment: @Llama yeah you are right! but is there a way to do this other than replace? coz I have to modify a various files :(

Comment: @Bizhan no, I want the source to be changed

Comment: `I have to change one field in the json. As I rewrite the file, during git diff all the lines would change due to whitespace.` ?w=1 in github to ignore whitespace.

Comment: Then don't commit lines that only have whitespace changes? https://handyman.dulare.com/git-tips-and-tricks-for-every-day-usage/

Answer (score 0):

The code that adds the space is located in `JsonTextWriter.WriteIndentSpace`, and is called by the standard `JsonWriter`.

One possible option is to write your own `JsonTextWriter` derived class, override `WriteIndentSpace` and do nothing in it.

```cs
class MyWriter : JsonTextWriter
{
    public MyWriter(TextWriter sw) : base(sw)
    { }

    protected override void WriteIndentSpace()
    { }
}
```

You then need to write custom serialization code to actually use this writer

```cs
    static string Convert(object value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
    {
        JsonSerializer jsonSerializer = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(256);
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        using (var jsonWriter = new MyWriter(sw))
        {
            jsonWriter.Formatting = jsonSerializer.Formatting;

            jsonSerializer.Serialize(jsonWriter, value, null);
        }

        return sw.ToString();
    }
```

You can then call it with whatever settings you want, and an `IndentSpace` will never be inserted.

```cs
var json = Convert(myObject, new JsonSerializerSettings{ Formatting = Formatting.Indented });
```

Some of the code could be simplified if you know exactly what settings you want to use every time.

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LOR9uC)

Answer (score -4):

Replace `": "` by `":"` in json content with `string.Replace`

```
string fileName = "file.txt";
string jsonFromSerialization = "{\n\t\"foo\": \"bar\",\n\t\"bar\": \"foo\"\n}"; //JsonConvert.SerializeObject
jsonFromSerialization = jsonFromSerialization.Replace("\": \"", "\":\"");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonFromSerialization);
```

Replace `"<any number of whitespaces>:<any number of whitespaces>"`
eg. `"          :      "`
by ":" in json content with `Regex.Replace`

```
string fileName = "file.txt";
string jsonFromSerialization = "{\n\t\"foo\"     :     \"bar\",\n\t\"bar\"    :  \"foo\"\n}"; //JsonConvert.SerializeObject
string pattern = "\"\\s*:\\s*\"";
jsonFromSerialization = Regex.Replace(jsonFromSerialization, pattern, "\":\"");
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonFromSerialization);
```

Result
[image: file]

---

Another approach. Thanks to [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) for his suggestion.
In this example validates special strings in the value of a key.

eg.

```
{"foo":   "xyz\": ","bar"    :  "foo"}
```

Code

```
string JsonReplace(string json)
{
    string pattern = @"(\s*""\w+"")\s*:\s*";
    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(json, pattern))
    {
        json = json.Replace(m.Value, m.Value.Replace(" ", string.Empty));
    }
    return json;
}

string fileName = "file.txt";
var data = new
{
    foo = "xyz\": ",
    bar = "foo"
};
string jsonFromSerialization = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
jsonFromSerialization = JsonReplace(jsonFromSerialization);
File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonFromSerialization);
```

Result
[image: result]

Comment: Note that this won't work for anything other than string values, leading to inconsistent formatting. It feels *really* fragile, too - fundamentally, messing with the string representation of JSON, XML etc after generation is rarely a good idea IMO.

Comment: Example of how it's brittle... if you have a string value of `xyz": `, the JSON representation would be `"xyz\": "`... which this replacement will change to `"xyz\":"`.

Comment: You are correct, but your example is very very specific, placing json within the value of a key which is a bit far-fetched. It's something that the developer may not need to solve ->  Json inside the json.

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be JSON within JSON. It's just a string that ends with a double quote, colon, space. That's not JSON-specific - it's just a string. But fundamentally it shows how fragile this is. (And then there's the "only working with string values" aspect too, of course.) It's an approach I'd strongly recommend against.

Comment: And does it handle the key itself having colons and quotes? (Rare, but entirely valid - and feasible if you're serializing a `Dictionary<string, string>`.) I'd need to look really, really carefully to try to validate this - which would alarm me, because it's so easy to go wrong. As per the comment thread on the question itself, I think a far better solution is just *not to do this at all*.